# Regex to match groups with no specific order

Tags: java, regex

I have 4 complex regex patterns, `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. I need to locate all the patters that are of the format of `A(B AND C AND D)` where the order of `B,C,D` does not matter and `C` and `D` are optional. Is there a way to do such a thing in regex without writing all the possible permutations of `B,C,D` with or (`|`) between them?

I'm programming this in Java, and prefer to performance-friendly. Thanks!
Edit: Changing 3 complex patters to 4 complex regex patterns.

Comment: Is A,B,B,B an acceptable result?

Comment: Of course no. He wrote "without writing all the possible permutations of B,C,D with or (|) between them?" it means that ABBB is not a valid regex.

Comment: I was confused by A(B AND C AND D), and then immediately after saying C and D are optional.

Comment: @ohaal, Ademiban is correct - A,B,B,B is not an acceptable result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You have to write all the permutations. It is a limitation of the regular languages. Once you do it however, it will be as performance friendly as any other regular expression.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by "performance friendly as any other regular expression"? It seems that checking all the permutation is extremely performance-heavy...

Comment: Thats the beauty of regular expressions. You only pay for the number of characters you check, not how big the regular expression is. The size of the regular expression will "only" effect the time it takes for `Pattern.compile()` to run and the memory used by that `Pattern` object. If you want to know more look up Regular language and Finite-state machine on Wikipedia.